# Kubernetes Persistent Volume multithread access

Tags: multithreading, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a service that has single thread writer with multiple thread reader to a file deployed on k8.
Now I want to take advantage of the k8 persistent storage to save the huge load time in between pod restarts, by moving the file (1 writer, multi reader) to k8 persistent storage with local storage type. How would this affect my file lock?

I researched a lot online, and there are not a lot of mentioning of how multi threaded access would work on a persistent volume. Hope I could get some pointers on wether multi-threaded access would even work on persistent volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> by moving the file (1 writer, multi reader) to k8 persistent storage with local storage type. How would this affect my file lock?

In both cases the application interacts with the ***file on the filesystem***. So there will be no logical difference for your application.